# Not able to add divide numbers in bash which has an input from the curl command

Tags: bash, curl

I am making a bash script which calculates how many parts a file will have to be broken if downloaded in chunks.Like in this case it is 120mb.For getting the size of the file to be downloaded I am using curl command and then I am dividing it with 120mb(in bytes), but the variable part(no of parts) is not getting calculated.

Here's my code:

```
echo "Enter URL: "
read url
size=$(curl -sI $url |grep Content-Length|awk '{print $2}')
limit=$((120*1024*1024))
parts=$(($size/$limit))
echo $parts
```

I even tried using bc:

```
parts=$(echo $size/$limit|bc)
```

But parts is not getting any value.
Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong.

Comment: What is `$size`? Any trailing whitespace? Do you get any error, or is `$parts` just empty?

Comment: can you echo $size and $limit or provide the URL?

Comment: @itzhaki Yes , echo $size and echo $limit gives correct output and $(($limit/$limit)) works but $(($size/$size)) nor $(($size/$limit)) is working. Why is $size not being executed?

Comment: @Aaron $parts is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl -sI example.com | grep Content-Length | cut -d' ' -f2 | awk '{ print $1/(120*1024*1024) }'`

Comment: And how do I store it in a variable?

Comment: Like so: `varName=$(curl -sI example.com | grep Content-Length | cut -d' ' -f2 | awk '{ print $1/(120*1024*1024) }')`

Comment: And how to use $limit instead of 120*1024*1024?

Comment: Like so: `varName=$(curl -sI example.com | grep Content-Length | cut -d' ' -f2 | awk -v limit=$limit '{ print $1/limit }')`

Comment: Both `grep` and `cut` are unnecessary and inefficient here as `awk` can easily do it all.

Comment: Talking about efficiency in this context is preposterous

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do this in single `awk` as you cannot do floating point arithmetic in shell:

```
curl -sI "$url" | awk -F': *' '$1=="Content-Length"{print $2/(120*1024*1024)}'
```

To put this into a variable:

```
var=$(curl -sI "$url" | awk -F': *' '$1=="Content-Length"{print $2/(120*1024*1024)}')
```

Comment: And how do i store it a variable?